# C++ statically binding with C# without depending on VC++ runtime,

Tags: c#, c++, binding

Is it possible to use a C++ code statically binding with C#  without depending on VC++ runtime?

How to do that?

I have a algorithm in C# which I would like to try to write this in C++ to verify its efficency.

Comment: You simply can't bind statically to a managed C# program. You could use managed C++ (C++CLI?), but that is not entirely like normal C++. And I am not even sure if that can bind statically.

Comment: XY problem: "to verify its efficiency" you don't need to bind anything statically. You have to benchmark and compare.

Comment: But is it possible to call statically linked C++ (*.lib) from C# ? My solution is in C#...

Comment: @Henrique: no, it isn't. You can however call C++ (if it has a simple C interface or a COM interface) in a DLL, from C#.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, thank you very much. You comment was very useful!